# Как в всплывающей окне без перехода jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте. Как сделать в всплывающей окне без перехода на другую страницу в jquery.
Сделал при клике на ссылку(видео) открывается окно как в (facebook,vk) .Как сделать чтобы в открывшейся окне при клике на другое видео в открывшейся окне не переходило на другую страницу а оставался на этой странице , только видео изменялось . Сделал так не получилось переходит на другое изображение .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var collection = $('.pm-thumb-fix.pm-thumb-145');
    $(collection).click(function(){        
        var url=$(this).attr('href');
        $('#video-wrapper').load(url + '#video-wrapper');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: @fikos, моя твоя не понимать. Стоит понятный вопросе формулировать.

Comment: )) например при нажатии на ссылку открывается окно , внутри видео проигрывается и внизу в той же окне есть другии ссылки (видео) при нажатии на эти ссылки (видео) переходит на другую страницу с видео . Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на эти ссылки (видео) не переходило на другую страницу . @Volt